# Event firing before databinding is updated - how do I wait for the update?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, microsoft-metro

I'm currently encountering this issue while programming Metro, but I'm sure it applies to WPF, Silverlight and possibly even WinForms.

I have a databound TextBox and a method attached to the LostFocus event of the TextBox. When it loses focus, I want the code behind to trigger a save function in order to persist the data. The problem is that the LostFocus-event triggers before the business object is updated from the GUI through TwoWay databinding.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there some way to force update of the databinding from the LostFocus method (would probably be platform-specific)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to do some business logic instead of having the GUI update the textbox.  I would set the `Textbox` to only be `BindingMode.OneWay`, so that when the business object is changed the textbox is updated properly.

Then in the Lostfocus event (again wpf, but I think you'll get the idea):

```
private void EditBoxLostFocus( object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e )
{
   var textbox = sender as TextBox;

   //update your business object w/ textbox.Text value
   //other business logic
}
```

This way you're in full control of when the object gets updated, and can apply your business rules.

Comment: This will work. It just feels like I'm trespassing on the land of DataBinding when I do manual updating of the business object. Will accept answer unless something better comes up.

Comment: It depends on the context of what's happening.  If you're doing validation or something, this is the better place to do it, because this will prevent the textbox from setting your business object to something invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Set UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged on the TextBox binding.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Didn't fix my situation where clicking a button while a TextBox has focus causes the target property to be out of date.